# My project does not recognize an activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Does anyone know what this log mean and how can I repair it?

```
04-16 08:02:39.624: E/AndroidRuntime(20819): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.logoquiz/com.example.logoquiz.ChooseScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

this is the entire log

```
    04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.logoquiz/com.example.logoquiz.ChooseScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2355)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5520)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:324)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1912)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at com.example.logoquiz.ChooseScreen.onCreate(ChooseScreen.java:25)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2311)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    ... 11 more
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    ... 23 more
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x5/d=0x1001 a=4 r=0x7f040000}
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1927)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3354)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:438)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:176)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:172)
04-16 08:18:38.494: E/AndroidRuntime(22245):    ... 26 more
```

this is the main activity:

```
package com.example.logoquiz;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }   

    public void start(View v){





        Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, ChooseScreen.class);


        startActivity(intent);
        } 

    public void quit(View v){
           System.exit(0);
        } 



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

this is manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.logoquiz"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >  
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.logoquiz.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
           >


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>         



            </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.logoquiz.ChooseScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
           >

         </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.logoquiz.LevelMenu"

           >

         </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.logoquiz.LogoHall"

           >

         </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.logoquiz.quizscreen" 
           >

         </activity>


        </application>

</manifest>
```

when the app is running and it gets into the newq intent part it suddenly crashed and ive already declared on the new activity in the manifest can you see whats wrong here?

Comment: there seems to be some issue in either namespace, or class name mentioned in one of your xml files. Here is the check list, 
1) Check all the tags,
2) Check any package name used as a tag eg. <com.test.mystuff.myactivity />

Comment: Post your activity_main xml.

Comment: Check your layout file. When I got this issues it was because there was a > or a < left in the code in some place.(Usually at the end and start of the tags)

Comment: You are getting an exception while trying to inflate your layout XML in com.example.logoquiz.ChooseScreen.onCreate(ChooseScreen.java:25). Post your layout file that you are passing to `setContentView()`

Answer (score 0):

are you inflating any xml inside ChooseScreen class.

If yes then are you inflating using getApplication(), if yes then change it to this.
I have had the same issue and while inflating changed getApplication() to this, and this issue was resolved..

Hope it will help you as well... please try ...